# Clio webhooks custom field

Tags: clio-api

I develop my own integration with Clio. We have a lot of customers which use Clio app. And what I want is to sync contacts with our app and have a real time knowledge about changes(create,delete, change) in contacts model. So we decided to use webhooks.

Webhooks works good and we love it, but have a litte issue. We have a lot o customers which use Clio and have a lot of incoming changes as well.

The issue is we can't recognize which webhook came from, which user made the changes. So my question is - is it possible to create some custom field like "clio_profile_id" to get a clio user id in it? You can see screentshot i've attached. A lot of fields, but no field to recognize a user.

What I mean exactly is - when you create webhook for the first time in some apps it's possible to create 'custom field' ant this custom field will be displayed at every webhook. See screnshot for example.

I didn't find anything about this in API Documentation https://app.clio.com/api/v4/documentation.

[Example of a custom field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IX12U.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that but you'll run into a problem because you can't query the custom fields by their name, only by their internal ID. Therefore you'll have to manually build all the webhook receivers with their own internal ID filters for each of your clients.

I've built a webhook tool for [Clio API](https://workload.co/clio-api) that visualizes their API and also automates workflows and connects to other apps. Imagine a Zapier but just for Clio.

I'm one of the founders of [Workload](https://workload.co) and would love to get your feedback on the tool if you found it useful. We have a generous free trial.

~Bryan